# 401-Unauthorized when calling UmbracoAuthorizedApiController from backoffice

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

### Problem

When I change my controller to **inherit from UmbracoAuthorizedApiController instead of UmbracoApiController** I will get 401-Unauthorized and I will be redirected to loging page.

### Mode Details

I want to call some of my backend Api's from the back-office and to do that I've followed the article [in our.umbraco](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Implementation/Controllers/).

First I've implemented a controller inheriting from UmbracoApiController to be able to call my services from postman. Everything went fine and I could call my code and read data from Umbraco:

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/admins")]
 public class AdminsController : UmbracoApiController
 {
      [HttpGet]
        [Route("getdata")]
        public DataViewModel GetData(string id)
        {
          ....
         } 
 }
```

Then I've called my service from JavaScript in Dashboard using the plugins

```
  $http.get(vm.baseUrl + '/getdata?id=' + id, {})
            .then(function (response) {....}
```

Everything works fine, I can see that my cookies (containing token) has been sent in the request headers.

[image: token in request]

Then I've updated my controller to inherit from **UmbracoAuthorizedApiController** and now I don't have access to my Apis.

The controller is now like this:

```
   [RoutePrefix("api/admins")]
    public class AdminsController : UmbracoAuthorizedApiController
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Umbraco has two types of membership: back office and front end. Are you sure the credentials you are using to log in and test authentication are back office?

Comment: Try removing the route prefix attribute and see if that works?

Comment: @Juan, you mean Members and Users? :) I am using users because I am logged in to my Umbraco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorized controllers (same as other wrapped MVC controllers in Umbraco) are automatically routed. Backoffice authorisation will work when */umbraco/backoffice/* path will be present in the route.

Check: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/Authorized/
and: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/authorization

It's directly said:

> In order for Umbraco to authentication a request for the back office,
>   the routing needs to be specific. Any URL that routes to :
>
> /umbraco/backoffice/*
>
> will be authenticated. If you have a controller
>   that is not routed within the prefix, it will not be authenticated for
>   back office use.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that now :)

Comment: No probs! Let me know if it fixed your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :) it has fixed the problem

Comment: Good to know! Happy further coding :)